# Cluster points disappear when creating a webmap

Tags: qgis2web

I have styled the layer to have cluster points rather than individual points. I need to create a webmap (using qgis2web plugin) of the map. Before I styled the layer to have cluster points all my layers showed up fine when producing a webmap. As soon as I changed the style to have cluster points, the preview of my webmap doesn't display the points. Does anyone know the reason why these are disappearing?

Comment: You seem to have tagged this with the wrong software. Please explain in the question body how ArcGIS Online is involved or provide more information on the exact software components in use.

Comment: Apologies I don't know how this works. I am using a desktop version 3.2.1

Comment: Please take the [Tour] to better understand how GIS SE operates.

Answer (score 1):

Try not clustering the points in QGIS, and instead selecting the Cluster option in the qgis2web dialog. At the moment, qgis2web doesn't detect QGIS3 clustering, but there is an open ticket for the issue (https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/377).